# TYPO3_REQUEST_HOST no HTTPS

Tags: php, https, typo3, typo3-8.7.x

im using the mindshape-cookie-hint-extension. This extionsion includes the CSS-files with this line:

```
        $this->response->addAdditionalHeaderData(
        '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"  href="' .
        GeneralUtility::getIndpEnv('TYPO3_REQUEST_HOST') .
        '/typo3conf/ext/mindshape_cookie_hint/Resources/Public/Css/' . $style . '.css" />'
    );
```

The problem is that this line ignores the HTTPS-protocol and icludes the CSS-files with HTTPS and not HTTPS.

does anybody have a solution?

regards,

Answer (score 0):

you're writing "includes the CSS-files with HTTPS and not HTTPS." Can you explain what you mean?

Apart from that. It should be fairly easy to change the line to

```
    $this->response->addAdditionalHeaderData(
    '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"  href="' .
    GeneralUtility::getIndpEnv('TYPO3_SITE_PATH') .
    'typo3conf/ext/mindshape_cookie_hint/Resources/Public/Css/' . $style . '.css" />'
);
```

Comment: GeneralUtility::getIndpEnv('TYPO3_REQUEST_HOST') outputs "HTTP://www.example.com and not HTTPS://www.example.com".
When i try  "echo GeneralUtility::getIndpEnv('TYPO3_SITE_PATH');" i just get an "/".

Comment: that should be ok, as then the same server (with the same protocol) is used.

Answer (score 0):

Enable List view in WEB section and click on a root page. Check if you have added Domain inside that does not have a redirect to path. If you have, disable that domain. [image: emptdy typo3 domain]

Also, please check if you have set up absRefPrefix correctly